# Core Data NSPredicate fetch on entity relationship using in clause

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I would like to be able to search the relationship of an entity using an IN clause.
I have the following setup:
[image]

I would like to send over an array of nicknames and find all Persons associated with those nicknames.

```
//array of names to find
let nameArray: [String] = ["Tom", "Tommy", "Thomas"] 

// find all Persons who have a nickname associated with that person           
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY Person.nickName in %@",nameArray)
var fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
fetch.predicate = predicate
var fetchError : NSError? = nil

// executes fetch
let results = context?.executeFetchRequest(fetch, error: &fetchError)
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (ANY Person.nickName IN {"Tom", "Tommy", "Thomas"})'**

What am I doing wrong here? If I remove the predicate search, it returns all the results ok, but as soon as I add this line in, everything breaks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use the relationship name in your `NSPredicate`.
Try this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY personToNick.nickName in %@", nameArray)
```

Comment: @Para can you tell me the objective C alternative for this swift code ?

Comment: Sure, here you go: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY personToNick.nickName in %@", nameArray];`

Comment: What is use of ANY?

Comment: I don't think so, it's one-to-many relationship, personToNick is a set.