# Using objects as CoreData object field type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

Is it possible to configure CoreData object field type as an object ?, for example "CustomTimeObject":

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension someObject{

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SomeObject> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SomeObject>(entityName: "SomeObject")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var startTime: CustomTimeObject


}
```

My intention is to use a predicate when calling to Core Data in order to retrive objects with matching "startTime" specific CustomTimeObject field, for example (even though not working):

```
            var customTime = [CustomTimeObject]
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
              

            let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
              
     
    
            let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "SomeObject")


            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "startTime.hour > %@ AND startTime.minutes < %@", argumentArray: [8, 11])


              do
              {
                  let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
              
                
                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                        var timeObject = CustomTimeObject()
                        timeObject.hour=result.value(forKey: "startTime.hour")
                        timeObject.minutes=result.value(forKey: "startTime.minutes")
                        customTime.append(timeObject)
                }
                
              
     
                 
              }
                
              catch
              {
                  print(error)
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make CustomTimeObject as another entity and make it as a relation inside your first someObject. Look into this link from Apple : [Creating Managed Object Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html)

Comment: Could you provide an example of code implementation ?

Comment: Can you set NSPredicate on an object(in a relation) field, like NSPredicate(format: "startTime.hour > %@ AND startTime.minutes < %@", argumentArray: [8, 11]) if CustomTimeObject  was in relation?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that, look into this link for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158610/core-data-nspredicate-fetch-on-entity-relationship-using-in-clause